# Django receives "FATAL: password authentication failed for user" even though user crendntical are correct

Tags: django, postgresql, python-3.6

Some background:
I'm trying to install the [arches project](https://github.com/archesproject/arches) on Windows. After some problems, I've seen it is recommended to run it on Linux, so now I'm running on Ubuntu terminal for Windows.
As for the error:
The first step is to run the `python manage.py setup_db` command. It fails with:

```
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "kali"

Error connecting to db with these settings: dbname=jerarch user=kali host=localhost port=5432

Have you created the database yet? The quickest way to do so is to supply Postgres superuser credentials in the PG_SUPERUSER and PG_SUPERUSER_PW settings, and then re-run this same command.
```

Also:

- User "kali" exists, and I've set its password using `ALTER USER kali WITH PASSWORD 'xxxxxxxx';`
- `psql -U kali -d jerarch` works fine, and only with the password I set before (meaning the `ALTER USER` worked).
- `PG_SUPERUSER` and `PG_SUPERUSER_PW` are defined as needed.

I really don't know what else to do. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just before publishing the question, I figured out that the problem was the duplicate `postgresql` enivronments: one was running on my Windows, and the other was running on the virtual Ubuntu.
Using the Ubuntu cli for `psql` addressed the Ubuntu postgres, while for some reason `djnago` on Ubuntu addressed the Window's postgres. The `kali` user was atcually configured there too, but with another password.